# Enviar XMLHttpRequest() para um método de uma classe

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

Tem alguma forma de fazer `request.open('post', 'server.php');` chamar um método de uma classe php direto ao invés de chamar um arquivo?

Comment: Você usa algum framework ou PHP puro só?

Comment: Você precisa de um [*front controller*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) para receber as requisições e mapear um dos parâmetros para a classe e método adequado. Ou usar um microframework como o [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) que faça isso por você.

Comment: Obrigado, vou verifica as duas opções.

Comment: Bom dia, Matheus! Existe sim, criei um exemplo para que você possa conferir.
Basta seguir o link abaixo do GitHub: https://github.com/williamurbano/exemplos/tree/master/request-class-method